# Delete All K8s Pods from a specific namespace

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I want to remove all the pods from a specific namespace through Ansible Play. Here , I'm trying to delete all the postgres pods from a namespace 'postgres-ns'.

I'm using below ansible play to remove it:

```
- name: Unistalling postgres from K8s
  block:
     - name: Removing Statefulsets & Service from  "{{postgres_namespace}}"
      action:
        shell kubectl -n "{{postgres_namespace}}" delete statefulsets "{{postgres_release_name}}" && kubectl -n "{{postgres_namespace}}" delete service "{{postgres_release_name}}"-service
      register: postgres_removal_status
    - debug:
        var: postgres_removal_status.stdout_lines
```

but getting this error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): statefulsets.apps \"postgres\" not found
```

This is the result from `kc -n postgres-ns get all`:

```
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE`

`pod/postgres-postgresql-0   1/1     Running   0          57s`

`NAME                                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE`

`service/postgres-postgresql            ClusterIP   10.108.64.70   <none>        5432/TCP   57s`

`service/postgres-postgresql-headless   ClusterIP   None           <none>        5432/TCP   57s`

`NAME                                   READY   AGE`

`statefulset.apps/postgres-postgresql   1/1     57s
```

Can some one help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you update ```delete statefulsets "{{postgres_release_name}}"-postgresql``` and check? and what is the value of ```postgres_release_name```?

Answer (score 1):

> `Error from server (NotFound): statefulsets.apps \"postgres\" not found`

This says that you want to delete a statefulset which name is `postgress`, But from your `get all` command the name of statefulset is `statefulset.apps/postgres-postgresql`. You need to update `delete statefulsets "{{postgres_release_name}}"-postgresql` or pass correct value of `postgres_release_name`?